# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute <Variable>

Tags: python

I need to access global variable (g). which was present in another python file inside the class. Please suggest me how to access.

test1.py:

```
class cls():
    def m1(self):
       inVar = 'inside_method'
       global g
       g = "Global"
       x = 10
       y = 20
       print("Inside_method", inVar)
       print (x)
       print (y)
       print (g)
obj = cls()
obj.m1()
```

test2.py:

```
from test1 import *
print (cls.m1) # I can access all variables in method
print (cls.m1.g) # getting error while accessing variable inside the function
```

I expected to access variable 'g' from my test2.py. Could you please help me out.

Comment: `g` simply does not belong to `m1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globals are attributes of the *module*, not the `c1` class or `m1` method. So if you imported the module instead of all the names from the module, you could access it there:

```
import test1

# references the `m1` attribute of the `cls` name in he `test1` module
# global namespace.
print(test1.cls.m1)
# references the `g` name in he `test1` module global namespace.
print(test1.g)
```

You also run the `cls().m1()` expression at the top level in the `test1` module, so it is executed the first time anything imports `test1`. This means that your `from test1 import *` expression created a name `g` in your `test2` namespace too:

```
from test1 import *  # imported cls, obj and g

print(g)  # "Global"
```

However, that reference will not change along with any assignments to the `test1.g` global.